# How can i save the url of a page after form submitting in a session using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a simple search form on my website and i want to save the url generated by this search form after submitting it in a session:

I tried something like that:

```
<?php  
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on')   
    $url = "https://";   
    else  
    $url = "http://";   
    $url.= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];   
    $url.= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    
    $_SESSION['page'] = $url;
    echo  $_SESSION['page'];  
  ?>
```

So far so good. After form submission I can get/echo the generated URL which is something like this:

```
https://mysitecom/search?country=USA&city=New_York
```

My problem is that if I leave from the page and then click again the nav button that links back to the search page the url is:

`https://mysitecom/search` instead of  `https://mysitecom/search?country=USA&city=New_York` which is what i want.

What I am doing wrong? Is there any other way to get what i need?

Comment: You're overriding the value of the url variable on each get request without checking if the request has search params set or not thus leading to current url

Comment: @Designer, Keep a back button in the website, upon clicking the back button, write a javascript to open the URL which is stored in session

Comment: @sree it works ok when i click the back button. The problem is when i click the link to the specific page url. Example: `<a href="mysitecom/search">Search Page</a>` I am really struggling to find a solution!

Comment: would `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` cover your needs? No, my bad

Comment: When the PHP script for the search the URL is executed, if there are no parameters already in the URL, you'd have to check if there was a previous URL (or just set of parameters) saved in the session, and then redirect the browser to that saved URL instead. Only save the new URL to the Session if it has parameters (doesn't matter if they're the same ones, no harm done if you override the existing ones with the same thing again).